# A calculator that shows both hex and decimal at the same time

Tags: calculator, hexadecimal

I'm looking for a Windows calculator that has a dual dec/hex display.
That is, assuming I'm adding in Hex mode, I want to have another line showing me the decimal value of my current Hex calculation.
Something like:
Display1:            0x1000
Display2:              4096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using PCalc from analogX since I can remember.
 It is a calculator aimed at programmers. You can type stuff just as you would in 'C' or a few other programming languages for that matter.
A great feature is that all results are displayed in various ways: dec, hex, oct, bin etc..
You can mix the different bases to your liking.
e.g.: 0xcee + 3310
or even more 'advanced' stuff like: sin(0xcee)
as well as all other operations known from programming: 0xcee >> 3, !1, ^0xcee

It can be downloaded for free from [AnalogX website](http://analogx.com/contents/download/Programming/pcalc/Freeware.htm).

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for - but a good headway :)

Answer (score -1):

If you’re using Windows 7 then it’s got an in-built calc to do this without needing to download third-party calcs.